# I'm creating a programme on Python that has encrypted words and I' can't find a solution in order to swap the words with characters.

Tags: python, encryption

In my program there are a selection of encrypted words which include all 26 letters of the alphabet for example the words is 'ACQUIRED', but encrypted it is '#+/084&"'. In the program the user has sees the encrypted code and is given a few hints to get them started, they have to substitute letters in for characters, unfortunately I am not very experienced and I don't know how to do this. Please Help.

Comment: One approach is to use [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) and [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

Comment: lol thats my answer :P (I was typing it as you made the comment:P)

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
encode_table = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
                 ",./<>?;':\"[}{]\\|=+-)(*&^%$")
encode_tab = string.maketrans(*encode_table)
decode_tab = string.maketrans(*encode_table[::-1])

print "acquired".translate(encode_tab)
print ",/=(:+><".translate(decode_tab)
```

is probably the simplest for a simple substitution cipher